# In Google Sheets, how do I delete a row based on the lack of presence of a certain value in a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example. I have a Google Sheet that's hundreds of rows long. There's a column that is sorted by the question "what are your 3 favorite fruits?" at the end of it. I want to be able to delete all rows that don't have "apple" in the appropriate column, so that I see everyone who listed apple as one of their three favorites. I would like to be able to see their other information (email address, age, etc.) in the rest of the row. The end goal is that I have a Google Sheet with someone who listed "apple and banana" or just "apple". How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome. Do read [ask] and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically?  If not, it's relatively easy to create a filter and then just delete the filtered rows.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee Good call, this is working great! I didn't need to do it programmatically, filters are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete Row if Column 1 is not 3

```
function deleteRow() {
  const ss = Spreadsheet.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] != 3) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  })
}
```